# Strange divider with the v7 support actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

The used theme for the actionbar is `Theme.AppCompat.Light` when using `Theme.Holo` the issue does not exists.

I am using a custom view for the support v7 actionbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And I get the following result :

[image]

How do I remove the black line/divider between the layout and the actionbar.

I have tried changing the actionbar style but with not much of a success.

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="dividerVertical">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here is my Activity Source:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    }


}
```

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.actionbartest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.actionbartest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 20):

You're probably looking for the [`android:windowContentOverlay`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowContentOverlay) attribute.

To remove that drop shadow, simply set the value to `@null` in your theme, like so:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Setting the android:windowContentOverlay to null didn't seem to help.

Comment: Not sure if it's intentionally, but your manifest shows a different theme definition for the `MainActivity`, which overrides the theme set in the application tag. You may want to remove the line that says `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` and try again.

Comment: is was only for testing to see if it works with Holo theme, forgot to remove it, and the 'divider' still there when the Theme.AppCompat.Light is used.

Comment: Have you also added the non-prefixed attribute equivalents in your theme declaration? Just asking because I don't see them in your code snippets. For example: `android:actionBarStyle` should be accompanied by an `actionBarStyle` attribute in order for the style to be correctly picked up on pre-ICS devices. Basically every attribute will need to be declared twice: once from `android.attr.R` (with `android` prefix), and once from `appcompat.R.attr` (no prefix). That's the only correct way to support both newer and older devices. Read the [ActionBar Styling guide](http://goo.gl/LZbzfN).

Comment: @MH: I know that we have to define attributes twice in order to get it working in old versions. But eclipse gives error when I just write "windowContentOverlay" without the "android:" prefix. Is it normal for v7?

Comment: @Mehmed: Any chance you added the v7 support library as a jar? That way you will *not* be able to use any of the embedded resources, including styles. Make sure you add the v7 support library using the steps outlined under "[Adding libraries with resources](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)".

Answer (score 7):

> How do I remove the black line/divider between the layout and the actionbar.

I think you are mistaken. There really *isn't* a divider present. To confirm:

Open the layout file you're using with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Whatever the base container is, set its background to the color you use with the ActionBar. For example, let's say that the base container is a LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >      <<<====== Add this

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You'll see that the ActionBar now blends with the activity's view.

What you are currently seeing is a gradient defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#ffe8e8e8"
    android:endColor="#ffffffff"
    android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Here's where the background comes from:

```
(taken from platforms/android-17/data/res/values/themes.xml)
<style name="Theme.Light">
    <item name="windowBackground">@android:drawable/screen_background_selector_light</item>
    ....
```

To get rid of it, you can either give your base container a background color, or override this attribute's value in your project's `res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>        
</style>
```

**Edit:**

This is the project setup:

res/layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivityCompat" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    </style>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.trialcompat.MainActivityCompat"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivityCompat.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivityCompat extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    }
}
```

`R.layout.actionbar` is the same as the one you have posted in the question. And this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, I cannot reproduce the divider issue. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the actionbar compact, I have tried using a Theme.Holo and there was no divider.

I have tried overriding the android:windowBackground attribute and it didn't help.

Comment: @user1940676 Please read through my edit above. Can you tell me how to replicate the issue you are having?

Comment: I have tested it on 4.3 and it seems to work there, but it didn't work with previous versions.(4.1/4.2/2.2)

Comment: @user1940676 You are right. I was testing on 4.3, and it was working. I just tested on 4.2.2 and that horizontal divider showed up. Tried getting rid of it but nothing works.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I might just get back to using actionbar sherlock until they fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Beside @Vikram answer, add this to the theme:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:color/white</item>
```

Recommendation: Use the same color you use on your layouts. For the default one, use `@null`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After lots of trials and fails I found that the bug was because of the  9patch background of the action bar.
I switched the 9patch with a regular image and the black line was gone.

Answer (score 0):

**For api version >= 21**

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
appBarLayout.setOutlineProvider(null);
```